# Horizontal rows with unknown amount

Tags: html, css

I wish to create X different rows that are horizontally floated. (see image.) The problem i'm having is that i can't set the width of the container since i don't know exactly how much rows will be added.

At the moment i have this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">                  
            <div class="row">
                Lots of content
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                Lots of content
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                Lots of content
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                Lots of content
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row  {
    float:left;
    width:23%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    background-color:#252525;
    height:500px;
    color:white;
}

.container {
    width:500%;
}
```

The width of the container needs to be changed every time there has been a new row added or deleted. Is there a any way to solve this?

[image: Horizontal scrolling problem]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use "flex".

CSS:

```
.row {
  flex: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp
and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: This doesn't result in what i want to have. (see image, the screen is the line)